# Blockchain.info Shared Send

Tags: blockchain.info, services, mixing

Can anyone comment on the trustworthiness of blockchain.info's mixing service (shared send). Also would it be possible for things to go wrong internally resulting in my loss?

Comment: Blockchain.info is run by puik, a highly trusted member in the bitcoin community. If things were to go wrong he would right it immediately.

Comment: This would have been more appropriate in a comment. Being trustworthy is only part of the equation, the other being competent. Of course he is competent too, but still this isn't much of an answer (not that the question was a great one).